# Power Failure Detection Circuit via Flip-Flop

Tags: microcontroller, power, latch

I'm trying to create a circuit that will detect complete power failure. I think I understand what major components I need, but I'm unsure as to how to go about connecting them.

My plan is to take 3.3V line input, and somehow wire it up to a latching switch to preserve state information. Ideally I would also store information on [this flip-flop](http://www.ti.com/document-viewer/SN74LVC1G80-Q1/datasheet/pin-configuration-and-functions#SCES2215779). Output of the flip-flop would go to a microcontroller that could perform some analysis to determine if the latching switch changed states, thus determining that the power went completely off.

I just don't know where to begin in terms of selecting components or wiring them together. If anyone has some tips or suggestions for where to look, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Define threshold for power Good and Failure in terms of level, tolerance and duration..

Comment: Sure. Good should be 3.3 - 0.5V. Failure should be 0.5 - 0 V. Duration should ideally be any instance of voltage being below 0.5V.

Comment: What voltage do you plan on using for your flip-flop? I'm talking about supply voltage, not input voltage.

Comment: Is  this  a shared voltage, what about 0.5 to 2.8V?

Comment: @KingDuken I believe the supply voltage, Vcc, will be 3.3V.

Comment: What's the use of storing information on a flip-flop if both the microcontroller and the flip-flop will reset when the power fails? You could just store the same information on the microcontroller.

Comment: @immibis I see what you're saying about the flip-flop. I suppose that's why I mentioned the latching switch first, since it can store a state irrespective of power. The microcontroller will lose power too. Ideally it will check the state of the latching switch on next startup and determine that a power failure occurred. I'm looking for an idea for a circuit diagram so I can figure out how to depict this thing and calculate specific component values after that.

Comment: Don't you already know that a power failure occurred because the microcontroller is starting up? If a power failure hadn't occurred, then the microcontroller would've been running for some time already.

Comment: *Don't you already know that a power failure occurred because the microcontroller is starting up?*  My thought also. A cold-start should be the default. If you have other types of resets or startups, detect those.

Comment: How else can your processor be reset? What microcontroller are you planning to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect that the power has failed because the microcontroller is starting up.

If the power just came on, then it must have been off before. Therefore, there was a power failure.

Perhaps I haven't understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A flip flop will lose it's state if not powered. A better method would be to have a routine to write a counted value to a ROM. If the counter started from zero then you would know about an upset.

Another way to do this would be to use an [RTC IC](https://www.st.com/en/clocks-and-timers/real-time-clock-rtc-ics.html) and a microcontroller

You could also have a [brown out detection circuit](https://scienceprog.com/microcontroller-brown-out-detection/) and a enough power to run the micro for a few ms if the power failed to finish or log that the power was off.