# Can RTC IC detect power cut situation?

Tags: microcontroller, rtc

I have been making research about power down detection on Google. The only battery powered IC in my circuit is PCF85063 RTC IC.

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/443513/power-failure-detection-circuit-via-flip-flop) @VoltageSpike says that it is possible with using RTC IC and microcontroller. How can I detect power down situation and determine the time with PCF85063?

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to achieve here, can you elaborate? _"detect power down situation and determine the time"_. The time of what? The RTC needs power in _some_ form to operate.

Comment: I want to know if power down situation happened and calculate the power outage time. For example if power was down for 25 seconds, I want to know that power was gone for 25 seconds.

Comment: Such information should be in the device's datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you understood VoltageSpike correctly. I don't know of any RTC that traces power outages, and the PCF85063 is no exception.

---

One possible solution might be:

- Sample the RTC let's say each second and store the time in some non-volatile location.
- This location could be the alarm registers, and the RTC is the only device in your project providing such location as you told us.
- A possible alternate location is EEPROM, if your MCU provides such. But please be aware that EEPROM cells wear out over time, and some of them quickly.
- At restart of the MCU read the alarm registers and compare them to the running time. Calculate the difference and you know the duration of the outage.

This works only, if:

- You don't need the alarm for its primal purpose.
- The outage is not longer than one month, as the alarm registers only consist of second, minute, hour, and day of month. However, there is a byte without any dedicated function named RAM, which could take the month.

---

Another idea is to use the countdown timer.

- Setup its clock frequency to 1 Hz to count seconds.
- As long as the MCU runs, reset the timer to a high start value each second.
- At restart read its value and calculate the difference.

Be aware of:

- The timer has only 8 bits, limiting the measurable duration to a bit more than 250 seconds.
- The timer automatically overflows, but since the MCU does not run, it misses these overruns. You cannot differentiate between outages of 120 seconds and 120 + n * 255 seconds.